# different calculating result in iphone and iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator, lapack

I have a program that needs to calculate the eigenvalues of a 8*8 matrix. I use the LAPACK (deyev_) to solve it. When I use the ios simulator, the results are the same as the paper we have which are right. But when I use the iphone to test it, the calculating results are not the same. Why is that? Someone says that it is because iphone's CPU is not strong as the MAC's, I have the all the elements of the matrix precise into almost 20 to 40 digits after the dot, because our method needs high precision. If it is because the precision problem, how can I solve it, could you give me some advices? Thank you.

Comment: Do you get only slightly different results, or garbage out?  If the latter, it may be that precision is mismatched (try `SEYEV_` in place of `DEYEV_`.)